# Wait for the server to listen before running tests

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai, chai-http

I am using Mocha + Chai + chai-http to test my server application. The thing is, it needs to do some stuff (mostly DB writes) before actually starting the server. And that crashes my tests, because the tasks that are needed to be run before the server startup are not executed yet. Here's the code that I'm using:

```
// server declaration, it's just a restify server
(async () => {
  await cron.scanDB();
  await user.updateEventRoles();
  console.log('started');

  server.listen(config.port, () => {
    log.info('Up and running, %s listening on %s', server.name, server.url);
  });
})();

...
module.exports = server;
```

And in tests:

```
chai.request(server)
  .get('/single/' + eventRes.body.data._id + '/organizers')
  .set('X-Auth-Token', 'foobar')
  .end((err, res) => {
    // some actual tests
```

What can I do to wait for the server to start before running tests?

Comment: Where and how do you start the server in the tests?

Comment: @MikaS well I don't, I just import `const server = require('../../lib/server.js');` in my test and chai does this automatically

Comment: You probably have to use the `done()` callback in a `before()` function to properly start the server. See the [documentation](http://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code) on async code, and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38223053/ensuring-server-app-runs-before-mocha-tests-start) answer. You basically tell Mocha to wait with starting the tests until `done()` has been called.

Comment: Here's a test setup that might be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63762896/whats-the-best-way-to-test-express-js-api/70479940#70479940

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your server.listen is wrapped in an async function and chai-http does not know to wait for that.  One thing you can do is use an event emitter and emit after the server is started.

Then at the top of your test create a before with an async function that returns a new promise that resolves when it receives the server started event.