# Mocking a config module with Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking

I'm trying to add tests around the use of a simple config object. Let's say I have:

**config.ts**

```
export default {
  foo: "bar",
};
```

**app.ts**

```
import config from "./config";

export default () => {
  return config.foo;
};
```

**app.test.ts**

```
import App from "./app";
import config from "./config";

describe("App", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.mock("./config", () => ({ default: { foo: "mock foo" } }));
  });

  it("returns a mocked value of config.foo", () => {
    config.foo = "baz";
    expect(App()).toBe("baz");
  });

  it("returns the default value of config.foo", () => {
    expect(App()).toBe("bar");
  });
});
```

The second test fails because the real config has been modified in the first test, but I want it to fail because the mock in the beforeEach has set the value to "mock foo". I think this has something to do with the config export not being a function, and so I can't do something like `jest.spyOn...`. However, if there's a way to mock an object, it'd save me a large refactor in the project I'm working on!

Comment: Either store and restore original value manually, or do full jest.mock routine, as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63763277/3731501

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jest.doMock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options) to mock `./config` module for each test case.

E.g.

`config.ts`:

```js
export default {
  foo: 'bar',
};
```

`app.ts`:

```js
import config from './config';

export default () => {
  return config.foo;
};
```

`app.test.ts`:

```js
describe('App', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });
  it('returns a mocked value of config.foo', () => {
    jest.doMock('./config', () => ({ foo: 'baz' }));
    const App = require('./app').default;
    expect(App()).toBe('baz');
  });

  it('returns the default value of config.foo', () => {
    jest.doMock('./config', () => ({ foo: 'bar' }));
    const App = require('./app').default;
    expect(App()).toBe('bar');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/65049305/app.test.ts (12s)
  App
    ✓ returns a mocked value of config.foo (8ms)
    ✓ returns the default value of config.foo (1ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.288s
```